# Get Soap envelope content in WCF Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

How can I get the content of Soap envelope when I have an exception in (my) Wcf Service ?

In deed, I have a simple Web service from which I want to send an email me an email, with soap envelope, when the Service catches an exception.

-- What I have --

I created a simple Web Service : Only two files + Web.Config

IHelloService.cs file :

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://www.example.com/")]
public interface IHelloService
{
  [OperationContract]
  string SayHelloTo(string name);
}
```

and, HelloService.svc file :

```
public class HelloService : IHelloService
{
   public HelloService() { }
   public string SayHelloTo(string name)
   {
        // Imagine I want to do something with all names with only 3 characters
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            if (name.Length == 3)
            {
                // Here, I want to have the soap envelope content passed to Ws
                // to do something with it, send it to someone, log it to file ...
            }
        }
     return "Hello " + name;         
   }
}
```

The Config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

-- End --

Comment: need a bit more info than this...

Comment: It's unclear. May you take Few minute and read [ask] and [MCVE]. Now that you know more about our guideline take your time to [edit] your question with more information. What is this exception you are talking about? What is it's meaning it's cause? Is it Something malformed send to the WebService? Is it an error in the process of the information? Is it an expected error?

Comment: But my gess is you have to warp Something in a try catch. build your mail and decide what you send back to the user.

Comment: I just posted the little Web service I have :)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable tracing on your WCF service.  This will help diagnose problems with the content to and from the service.   [Configuring Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing)